# Scala Slick filter with conditions over two left joined tables

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to reproduce this query in Slick.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN LEFT B AS B1 ON B1.aId = A.id && B1.condition = 'b1'
JOIN LEFT B AS B2 ON B2.aId = A.id && B2.condition = 'b2'

- (no condition, the query in a plain way)

- WHERE B1.status = 'delete' OR B2.status = 'delete'

- WHERE ((B1.status = 'read' AND B2.status <> 'delete') OR (B1.status <> 'delete' AND B2.status = 'read')

- WHERE B1.status = 'write' AND B2.status = 'write'

- WHERE B1.status = 'full' AND B2.status = 'full'

- WHERE ((B1.status = 'full' AND B2.status = 'write') OR (B1.status = 'write' AND B2.status = 'full')
```

I am not sure if this is possible

Up to now I have something like this

```
val query = for { ((a, b1Opt), b2Opt) <- ATable.aQuery join
  BTable.BQuery on ((joinTable, bTable) => join._1.id === _.AId && bTable.condition === "b1") join
  BTable.BQuery on ((joinTable, bTable) => join._1.id === _.AId && bTable.condition === "b2")
} yield (a, b1Opt, b2Opt)
```

and I am trying something like this

```
val filterB = query {
  case (a, b1Opt, b2Opt) => {
    bStatus match {
      case "delete" => b1Opt.map(b1 => b1.status === "delete") || b1Opt.map(b2 => b2.status === "delete")
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described, the two successive `left join`s of table B on table A's `id` should translate to something similar to the following:

```
val joinQuery = for {
  ((a, b1), b2) <- tableA joinLeft tableB on ( (x, y) =>
                            x.id === y.aId && y.condition === "b1" )
                          joinLeft tableB on ( (x, y) =>
                            x._1.id = y.aId && y.condition === "b2" )
} yield (a, b1, b2)
```

And a `where` condition of `B1.status = 'delete' and B2.status = 'delete'` should look like this:

```
val filterB = joinQuery.filter{ case (_, b1, b2) =>
  b1.filter(_.status === "delete").isDefined && b2.filter(_.status === "delete").isDefined
}
```

Note that with the `left join`s, `b1` and `b2` are wrapped in `Option`, hence the using of `isDefined` for the `and` operation.

As another side note, it might be worth considering to filter table `B` with `B.condition = 'b?'` to a reduced `B1` and `B2` before performing the `left join`s.

Comment: @Leo_C thank you for your answer. I can confirm that the join left are working the way you wrote. Something I did not mention is that status is also an Option[String], in the filter I am getting the following error "value && is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Option[Boolean]]]"